# Specifying margin between each child element of a gridview by column [ANDROID]

Tags: java, android, user-interface, gridview

Given this scenario : 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRSoA.png)

I'm trying to position every child elements of the gridview such that it will have specific margin value with the gridview child element that is directly above the element, and I would like the margin value (the vertical spacing between each child) to be consistent in relation to the Gridview child element directly above it.

From the context of the image uploaded above, I want to minimize the spacing between each child elements vertically given the case that each Gridview element's height is variable and I intend to keep it this way.
I'm also using a custom adapter to supply the items for the GridView.
Is there any method/XML attribute in a GridView class I can use to perform this task or do I need to use a custom view and override from GridView to implement this feature?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting the GridView item's XML margin attribute for the spacing that you want around the views. Gridviews don't have a setColumnHeight method so what you can do is set the View in the adapter to a set height. You can do that with `yourview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(w,h));`. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apparently GridView does not support this kind of implementation and I'll have to resort to using `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`.